# Rails: transform plain text to link with rails_autolink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, autolink

I have a rails app where users can post links inside a pin model. Here is the code to explain:

app/views/pins/_form.html.erb:

```
 <%= f.text_field :website, placeholder: "http://wwww.website.com" %>
```

And in my views:

```
<% if @pin.website.blank? %>
<% else %>
  <a href="<%= @pin.website %>" target="_blank">
<% end %>
```

It is working well if the users put the complete url (http://www.website.com) in the field, but if he forgets to add the 'http://' => (www.website.com) the page is obviously broken.

I was thinking to use the gem [auto_link](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) but I am a little bit confused on how to use it. Here is my config:

**gemfile.rb**

```
gem 'rails_autolink', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.6'
```

**views:**

```
<% if @pin.website.blank? %>
<% else %>
  <%= auto_link(@pin.website) %>
<% end %>
```

**application.rb**

```
require 'rails_autolink'
```

But it just doesn't work, the link appears as plain text. Any help, what am I missing. I have been looking on other thread, but nothing seems to resolve my issue...

UPDATE:
It is working well now if user passes the url just with the www. and without the http://, but is there a way to transform a raw text like this: website.com to http://www.website.com?

Answer (score 1):

auto-link still needs the prepended `HTTP` or `HTTPS` on the web address. My suggestion is going from the controller layer and parse it from there. If the submitted website does not have "http" in it, then add it.